# Codeception - Handling testing environments that use a subdomain prefix

Tags: codeception

I am trying to simplify my codeception testing. I have 26 subdomains and several testing environments. I have my Test Suite Configuration configured with my base-url, example.com. In each Cest I use amOnSubdomain to set the subdomain for the site, `$I->amOnSubdomain(subsite);` which gives me subsite.example.com

The problem I am running into is that my test environments are essentially a subdomain of each subdomain. So prod is subsite.example.com but if I want to run the tests against my Dev environment I need dev.subsite.example.com, and staging would be staging.subsite.example.com.

What I do now is create separate folders within Acceptance for production, and for each test environment. I copy each Cest file into each environment folder and modify the amOnSubdomain within each to match the environment. Each Cest is identical aside from the additional 'dev', 'test', or 'sandbox' in the subdomain for the test environments. I then can call each environment using the folder structure in the Codeception command, `codecept run tests/acceptance/prod` etc. This isn't the most efficient for long-term maintenance.

I know that the Environment configuration 'env:' allows you to set environment specific settings. It seems the right place to handle this, but setting the environment URL to something like test.example.com of course causes environment subdomain 'test' to be overwritten by the site subdomain when amOnSubdomain is called. I do not see another way to pass the environment subdomain through these settings. What I really need is to be able to set the environment URL to env.{{subdomain}}.example.com allowing {{subdomain}} to be replaced by the subdomain in the Cest.

Alternatively, a way to pass the environment variable from the execution command so that I can add it to the subdomain within the Cest file. I did see a PR that looked like it would meet my needs but it was rejected: https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/pull/3978.

I am assuming that there is a way to do this that I just haven't figured out yet.